# how i disable this in dyntopo sculpting?

Tags: sculpting, dynamic-topology

i did a test showing you this as you can see, the polygons in the plane get more deep when i scroll in or out,i do not want that the brush detail increase or decrease when i scroll in or scroll out to a sculpted mesh , any solution for this? [image] [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn on Constant Detail and the brush should behave the same zoomed in and zoomed out, same detail size but unfortunately the brush size will still increase and decrease by design.[image]
edit: Found it, hit that lock there on theleft of the radius and you can zoom in and out and the brush stays the same size :D
[image]

Comment: Wow, I have never seen that in tutorials before. Thank you for pointing that out.